# Не запускается консоль JUnit при запуске тестов через Suite.class

Tags: java, selenium, junit

Столкнулся с проблемой - если запускать тест в аннотации @Test в отдельном классе, то консоль JUnit открывается и отображается одна строка с наименованием запущенного теста и результатом его выполнения. В случае запуска тестов через runners.Suite вывод результатов теста не отображается. То есть консоль JUnit не запускается и списка тестов я не вижу.

Суть проекта заключается в запуске тестов и просмотре информации о их выполнении + время выполнения и т.п.

Вариант 1. Когда тест запускается отдельно:

```
    public class Test_GeneratePFXStoreOnAllSignParams {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static JSWebSignerWindowsAPI api;
    private String baseUrlNew = "file:///F://tmp/TestAPI/common/demo.html";
    public static final String currentDir = "resources/";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpOnce() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", currentDir + "geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"));
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("plugin.state.websigner", 2);
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 0);
        File extensionToInstall = new File("resources/websigner.xpi");
        profile.addExtension(extensionToInstall);

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary(binary);
        options.setProfile(profile);

        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        api = new JSWebSignerWindowsAPI(driver);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrlNew);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @Test
    public void example() throws Exception {
        String StorageType = "PFX";
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        api.commandOpenSession("25000");

        for (int i = 0; i < WebSignerVariables.PARAMS.values().length; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            api.commandCreateFileStorage(StorageType, WebSignerVariables.DEFAULT_IBANK_PASSWORD);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            api.commandGenerateKey(WebSignerVariables.PARAMS.values()[i].name(), 
                    WebSignerVariables.DEFAULT_IBANK_PASSWORD,  PARAMS.values()[i].getParams());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            api.commandSaveFileStorage(WebSignerVariables.PARAMS.values()[i].name() + "." + StorageType);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            api.commandForgetStorage();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void logout() {
        driver.close();
            if(driver!= null) {
                driver.quit();
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Результат выполнения теста]

**Вариант 2. Запуск через Suite.Classes**

**Class TestSuite:**

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ 
    Test_GenerateBIFITStoreOnAllSignParams.class
    })

public class TestSuite {

}
```

**Class TestRunner:**

```
public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore.runClasses(TestSuite.class);

        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestSuite.class);
        for (org.junit.runner.notification.Failure fail : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(fail.toString());
        }
        if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("All tests finished successfully...");
        }
    }
}
```

**Как заставить runners.Suite выполнять тот же анализ теста, что и junit.Test?**

**Прошу прощения за ошибки и кривые формулировки, опыта маловато.**

Comment: если мало опыта, бегите с эклипса на идею пока не поздно :)

Comment: Я пока не вижу разницы между IDE. Да и тут дело не в этом... я надеюсь :)

Comment: не, не в этом, это я так

Comment: а, вы запускаете его как JUnit тест или просто как приложение?

Comment: эмм... получается не как junit. Если я все правильно понял то main запускает runner.suite а он в свою очередь запускает по отдельности каждый тест.

Comment: мне не довелось заводить JUnit тесты на эклипсе, но нельзя ли запустить конфигурацию (Run as ...) как JUnit тест?